# XamlParseException in View

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, prism-4, xamlparseexception

I've got a view that shows only a Label.

The viewmodel is injected correctly in the view because the text of the label is bound to a viewmodel property.  Now, if I try to define a DataGrid in the xaml, I've got a XamlParseException:

> {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Type 'DataGrid' not found. [Line: 16 Position: 45]
>      su System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>      su Common.Views.FunctionalityView.InitializeComponent()
>      su Common.Views.FunctionalityView..ctor(IFunctionalityViewModel viewModel)}

BUT if I define a `DataGrid myDg = new DataGrid()` right before the `InitializeComponent();` it works.

I've checked all references and still can't find the problem.

Comment: Could you [edit] to add the *actual text of the exception*?  Your paraphrase makes it hard to understand what is going on.  Also, check for any inner exceptions as well.

Comment: The exception occurs in FunctionalityView constructor, InitializeComponent().

Comment: K, your default namespace has been messed up.  Create a new UserControl and look at all the xmlns definitions in the UserControl.  Compare them with the ones in your View.  Fix as needed.

Comment: If that was the issue, I have added an answer which explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your default namespace is messed up or missing.  Without the xaml, it is hard to tell what you should do.

An easy way to figure this out for yourself is to create a new UserControl, then examine and compare the xmlns namespaces defined on its root with the root element of your View.

WPF locates types by a specialized namespace definition.  It follows the format

> clr-namespace:[namespace](;assembly=[assembly name])

where

> [namespace]

is the namespace that contains the type definition.  And, if the type is defined within a different assembly from the one where the xaml file is located, you have to include the part within the preface.  `[assembly name]` is the name of the assembly without the .dll extension (e.g., `assembly=mscorlib` would import `mscorlib.dll`).  To import the Int32 type and use it within your xaml, you'll have to define the namespace

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

There also exists an [assembly-level attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) which allows you to assign a different namespace for *all types within an assembly*.  Typically, this takes the form of a URL.  This is by tradition rather than necessity, IIRC.  This is why some controls are identified with a more traditional namespace, such as

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

Comment: Thank you, i've checked my `xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"`  
    `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` and now it works